# Needed help in removing compilation errors in DPI and SV program

Tags: c++, verilog

Hi I am new for dpi programming. I am compiling small code[SV,C++ and DPI] in EDA playground. i am getting the compilation errors. I have attached code screen shot with this. And also I am giving my run command & errors also. Needed some help in removing the errors.

run command : `run -Q -unbuffered '-timescale' '1ns/1ns' '-sysv' 'my_dpi.cc' '-access' '+rw' design.sv testbench.sv`

errors:

```
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (testbench.sv,5|32): expecting a semicolon (';') [SystemVerilog].
ncvlog: *W,UEXPSC (testbench.sv,5|34): Ignored unexpected semicolon following SystemVerilog description keyword (SVrand).
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (testbench.sv,6|31): expecting a semicolon (';') [SystemVerilog].
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text, not screenshots. It's easier for others to help you if they can copy/paste your code - transcribing code from images is extra work for potential answer-ers.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I wll do.

Comment: I have removed all verilog errors. but some errors are coming in cc.

Comment: module export_ex1;
  export "DPI-C" function SVrand;
  export "DPI-C" task init_rand;
  import "DPI-C" context task my_C_task();
  task init_rand();
     $display("Desired seed 12345");
  endtask
  function int SVrand();
    return $urandom();
  endfunction
  initial
    my_C_task();
endmodule

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <svdpi.h>


using namespace std;


extern "C" int my_C_task() {
int num;
cout << "Starting C task\n" << endl;
init_rand();
num = SVrand();
cout << "Got %d from SV\n" << num << endl;
return 0;
}

Comment: [2019-12-17 11:10:07 EST] irun -Q -unbuffered '-timescale' '1ns/1ns' '-sysv' 'my_dpi.cc' '-access' '+rw' design.sv testbench.sv

Comment: "$TESTDIR/my_dpi.cc", line 11: error: identifier "init_rand" is undefined
  init_rand();
  ^

"$TESTDIR/my_dpi.cc", line 12: error: identifier "SVrand" is undefined
  num = SVrand();

Comment: Needed some help on this

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says: there is supposed to be a semicolon after `task init_rand` (line 5, column 32), not a pair of parentheses. Remove the parentheses.

You should look up examples of SystemVerilog syntax in your book, or online.